# Push receiver opening a new app everytime

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification

i am using the following to receive a push from parse.com

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class PushNotificationReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    private String pushUrl;

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
            pushUrl = json.getString("url").toString();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("url", pushUrl);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }


}
```

its working fine. problem is, when i tap a notification, its opening the app another time even if the app was open at that time.
Please advise.

Comment: btw, i tried FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP in place of new task. but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have solved it. 
added the following in menifest

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

and added my mainactivity as follows

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```